# Check for 3rd party app, open-if not install

Tags: android, android-intent, actionview

I am working on a class that when selected by the user should open an application. If that application is not installed they will click the "Find it" button and install it.

Here is what I have so far

```
public class calc extends Activity {
static final String MARKET_SEARCH_Q_PNAME_PROVIDER = "market://search?q=pname:com.packagename.package";



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.getpft);
    setTitle("Install Marine PFT?");

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Ok)).setOnClickListener(new Openpft());
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.FindIt)).setOnClickListener(new FindZxingOnclickListener());
}

public class FindZxingOnclickListener implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent marketLaunch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        marketLaunch.setData(Uri.parse(MARKET_SEARCH_Q_PNAME_PROVIDER));
        startActivity(marketLaunch);
    }}




    };
```

So far the page opens up and it searches correctly for the app. However now that the app is downloaded I need to automatically skip this screen and just open that app. How is that done?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, you are launching that app. Presumably, you have an `Intent` that you are passing to `startActivity()` that does this. If so, you have two choices:

1. Just call `startActivity()` and route to your above code in the `ActivityNotFoundException` `catch` block
2. Use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to see if anything will respond to your `Intent`, and if not, route to your above code without calling `startActivity()` first

Comment: Thank you for this. A follow up though, can I still wrap it in that if technically I have two options of content views to display? The first option is to show the new application. The second option is to bring them to a screen where they download that app if they don't have it. How would I handle that?

Comment: Also I don't want to use an onclicklistener for bringing up the app automatically. But all of the ways I see intents opening separate apps is via a button onclicklistener, can that step be skipped?

Comment: @Jim: "How would I handle that?" -- use an `if()` statement? This is your business logic in your app, not mine. "But all of the ways I see intents opening separate apps is via a button onclicklistener" -- you can call `startActivity()` from any sort of activity event listener (e.g., `onListItemClick()`).